# Check Current URL + filename for a Letters/Numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the domain AND check the filename for code.

Here is what I have:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example.com" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='x24'  ) {
    echo "x24 in filename found";
} elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="http://example.com" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='b48'  ) {
    echo "b48 in filename found";
} else {
    echo "nothing has been found";
}
```

So if the filename is `http://example.com/directory/abo-ame-ma-x24-file.php` I want it to be detected since the filename has **x24** in it. I would like to do the same thing for b48

Comment: And what is the question now? Do you get errors?

Comment: @RIzier123 no errors, it just displays the `else` statement even with the correct domain and file

Comment: Hey, welcome back Joe. Long time no see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i just used [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php))

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "http://example.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'x24') !== false ) {
    echo "x24 in filename found";

} elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "http://example.com" && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'b48') !== false ) {
    echo "b48 in filename found";

} else {
    echo "nothing has been found";
}
```

Comment: thanks! this works i will mark as correct when I can